# Optimize query for joining key/value pair tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

There are several topics I have tried and my own trial and errors but I can't get the following query to speed up. The query works fine but is just horribly slow :)

The topics I have read and tried:

[Need Help for Optimizing MySQL query with few joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697569/need-help-for-optimizing-mysql-query-with-few-joins)

[MySQL select from key/value pairs table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532673/mysql-select-from-key-value-pairs-table)

[Inner Joining two tables based on all "Key/Value" Pairs matching exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367651/inner-joining-two-tables-based-on-all-key-value-pairs-matching-exactly)

[Merging the result of two INNER JOINS of the same table into one single temporary table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279797/merging-the-result-of-two-inner-joins-of-the-same-table-into-one-single-temporar)

Here is the query I have:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`,`users`.`name`,`users`.`email`
FROM `test_users` AS `users`
LEFT JOIN `test_fields_values` AS `fields_values` ON
`fields_values`.`item_id` = `users`.`id`
INNER JOIN `test_fields_values` AS `fields_values_lastname` ON        
`users`.`id` = `fields_values_lastname`.`item_id`
WHERE 
(`fields_values`.`field_id` IS NOT NULL) AND 
(`fields_values_lastname`.`field_id` = 13)
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
ORDER BY `fields_values_lastname`.`value`
```

The tables look as follows. 
The user table:

```
id | name   | email
--------------------------------
1  | Myself | myself@example.com
```

The fields_values table, instead of the actual value I put in the name of the field to make it easier to understand I hope.

```
field_id | item_id | value
------------------------------------------------------------
4        | 1       | Address
5        | 1       | Phone
6        | 1       | City
7        | 1       | Zipcode
8        | 1       | Email
9        | 1       | Country
10       | 1       | Lastname
11       | 1       | H
12       | 1       | I
13       | 1       | J
14       | 1       | K
15       | 1       | L
16       | 1       | M
17       | 1       | N
```

The `item_id` field in the `fields_values` table matches the `id` field in the `users` table.

My goal is the following:

The `user` table has about 5500 entries in it and the `field_values` table has 13 entries for each user in it. What I am currently doing is getting a list of users ordered by lastname and show them in a list. This list has a filter, so the user list can be filtered on Country/City and a general search.

The filters apply on the `value` field fo the `fields_values` table. So I can get all users living in Belgium for example.

For each filter I add another innerJoin and so the query becomes like this:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`,`users`.`name`,`users`.`email`
FROM `test_users` AS `users`
LEFT JOIN `test_fields_values` AS `fields_values` ON
`fields_values`.`item_id` = `users`.`id`
INNER JOIN `test_fields_values` AS `fields_values_lastname` ON        
`users`.`id` = `fields_values_lastname`.`item_id`
INNER JOIN `test_fields_values` AS `fields_values_country` ON  
`users`.`id` = `fields_values_country`.`item_id`
WHERE 
(
(`fields_values`.`field_id` IS NOT NULL) AND 
(`fields_values_lastname`.`field_id` = 13)) AND 
(`fields_values_country`.`value` = 'belgium')
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
ORDER BY `fields_values_lastname`.`value`
```

Even without the filters applied the list takes like 2,5 minutes to load and `EXPLAIN` shows me that it retrieved 73979 records, which is approximately the total of 5500 * 13.

Any hints/tips/improvements are welcome. Thank you.

Edit:

`users` table

```
CREATE TABLE `test_users` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`username` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`usertype` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`block` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sendEmail` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`registerDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`lastvisitDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`activation` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`params` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `usertype` (`usertype`),
INDEX `idx_name` (`name`),
INDEX `idx_block` (`block`),
INDEX `username` (`username`),
INDEX `email` (`email`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci';
```

`fields_values` table

```
CREATE TABLE `test_fields_values` (
`field_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`item_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Allow references to items which have strings as ids, eg. none db systems.' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`value` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
INDEX `idx_field_id` (`field_id`),
INDEX `idx_item_id` (`item_id`(191))
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Hereby the explain:

```
id  | select_type | table                    | type     | possible_keys              | key            | key_len | ref                                        | rows    | extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"1" | "SIMPLE"    | "fields_values_lastname" | "ref"    | "idx_field_id,idx_item_id" | "idx_field_id" | "4"     | "const"                                    | "3513"  | "Using temporary; Using filesort"
"1" | "SIMPLE"    | "users"                  | "eq_ref" | "PRIMARY"                  | "PRIMARY"      | "4"     | "cms_inter.fields_values_lastname.item_id" | "1"     | "Using where"
"1" | "SIMPLE"    | "fields_values"          | "ALL"    | "id_id,idx_item_id"        | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                                       | "73979" | "Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)"
```

Comment: Why not use and in first join with field id 13

Comment: We'd actually need to see the EXPLAIN, as well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables

Comment: Also you have no aggregating functions here, so a GROUP BY clause is unwarranted

Comment: @VIPER Not sure if I did it wrong but adding the and in the first join with field ID 13 didn't seem to make any difference.

I have added the CREATE TABLE STATEMENTS and the EXPLAIN of the query. Removing the GROUP BY actually makes the query run about 5 minutes longer and I get duplicates in my result set.

Comment: @RolandD SELECT `users`.`id`,`users`.`name`,`users`.`email` FROM `test_users` AS `users` LEFT JOIN `test_fields_values` AS `fields_values` ON `fields_values`.`item_id` = `users`.`id` and `fields_values`.`field_id` = 13;

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes a world of difference to get the list. The next step would be to incorporate my ordering on the last name.

As soon as I leftJoin the `fields_values` table again, it becomes very slow. I guess I understand why, that is because it is linking the same table with all the rows against the same table which also has so many rows. Would it be better to do this in PHP instead of MySQL? or is there a MySQL solution as well?